# Angular 2/4 query string/params automatically converted to lower case

Tags: angular

I have an app built in Angular 4. 
When I am passing query string, it automatically converting Upper case characters to Lower case characters.

Below is original query string:

```
http://localhost:5001/create-password?resettoken=CfDJ8KiDnr7aa31ChHccXvdxPQtBOyrGdnLXfxHt5$2FSTLoPFZfXUz9VDLBwgEp2sseJTWGFcKtQ4u$2B8VvOk1UZjve3$2FqfV$2FAnwBXo$2BKHzAGsvd2juCemDVwzebGyT$2F77YK0wHvCBh0eg5zb1rr4udy$2Fy5Cr7aP3FaVFsizuB1tqFnqFTmCluv$2FpehjmdlDXxgv4BOD2xGShFGECx99F20nDpE4jS3bYgFnJnM94kZMPQO1HB2UrBJJU4p1Fb7991v$2Bi0nQ$3D$3D&username=nishantthakkar&type=recover
```

Below is auto converted query string:

```
http://localhost:5001/create-password?resettoken=cfdj8kidnr7aa31chhccxvdxpqtboyrgdnlxfxht5$2fstlopfzfxuz9vdlbwgep2ssejtwgfcktq4u$2b8vvok1uzjve3$2fqfv$2fanwbxo$2bkhzagsvd2jucemdvwzebgyt$2f77yk0whvcbh0eg5zb1rr4udy$2fy5cr7ap3favfsizub1tqfnqftmcluv$2fpehjmdldxxgv4bod2xgshfgecx99f20ndpe4js3bygfnjnm94kzmpqo1hb2urbjju4p1fb7991v$2bi0nq$3d$3d&username=nishantthakkar&type=recover
```

Can someone please tell me why it’s happening?